# What do you use for packaging/repackaging MSIs?

Tags: windows-installer, packaging, utility

I've been evaluating different MSI packagers with the intent of deploying installers for one custom application and several third-party applications (installer-chaining may be necessary in some cases). A developer will be working creating the MSI for the custom app, but the rest will be done by Operations-type people with little scripting experience. I've looked at products like MSI Studio, InstallShield, InstallAware, and Advanced Installer. All of them have a fairly similar options and decent enough pricing. Is there one utility in particular that has been found to work much better than others?

Comment: Should be a community wiki, please edit it to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work, we use InstallShield exclusively for packaging.

Comment: Thanks for the input. InstallShield is one of the products we've been evaluating and it seems to have a solid customization facet.

Comment: seems to be the widest-used, too, based on the number of installers that indicate "InstallShield" created them :)